# Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "sql"

Tags: php

I've got a problem when I write the command :

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql 'SELECT * FROM comment'
```

after enter I got this :

> 2019-03-24T13:20:10+00:00 [error] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:query:sql "'SELECT" "*" FROM "comment'"". Message: "Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "sql"."

Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "sql".

so what did I make so wrong ? thank you

Comment: Command runs fine. Are you sure that you enclose query in quotes?

Comment: yes I do... I have no ideo what i am doing wrong. I already checked all... but no clue what is going on

Comment: double quotes vs single quotes when Windows server. What is your host OS ?

Comment: My OS is windows 10

Comment: yes thank you, Alex... that solves the issue...

Answer (score 10):

Did you see [persisting-objects-to-the-database](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) this document?

> # on Windows systems not using Powershell, run this command instead: `php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM product"`

You need to use `"` double quote instead of `'` single quote

`php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM comment"`

Comment: using " double quote is the answer, Thanks @Saji!